# Как передать картинку через WebSocket?

Tags: angularjs, websocket, poco

Только начал изучать яваскрипт и ангуляр.
Использую библиотеку Poco для создания сервера.
Отсылаю картинку так:

```
int s, len; // здесь загружаю картинку из файла в буфер.
char* buff = CWebSocketServer::FileToBuffer( len ); 
WebSocket ws( request, response );
s = ws.sendFrame( buff, len, WebSocket::FRAME_BINARY ); // 54682 передано
```

Клиент на AngularJS принимает данные:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws");
...
ws.onmessage = function (msg) {

    console.log("Message received: " + msg.data ); // [object Blob] принят
    console.log("Message length: " + msg.data.size); // 54682 байта в блобе
    $scope.image = window.btoa(msg.data);
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}">
```

Чего еще не хватает чтобы картинка отобразилась? Правильно ли я вообще делаю?

Comment: Поскольку обработчик события `ws.onmessage` находится вне контекста angular, он не знает, что переменная `$scope.image` обновилась. Попробуйте после `$scope.image = window.btoa(msg.data);` написать `$scope.$apply();`.

Comment: $scope.$apply(); тоже использовал, не помогает :(

Comment: В таком случае надо посмотреть, что содержится в атрибуте `src` элемента `img`. Можно посмотреть в консоли браузера.

Comment: Вот строка из консоли
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,W29iamVjdCBCbG9iXQ==" src="data:image/JPEG;base64,W29iamVjdCBCbG9iXQ=="> == $0
Я не совсем понимаю что тут описано. Только начал изучать вэб

Comment: Не могу сказать, насколько верные у Вас данные в *base64*. Для исключения фактора angular, попробуйте изменить атрибут src с помощью нативного JS. Например: `document.getElementById('myImg').src="data:image/JPEG;base64,"+window.btoa(msg.data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь.
Оказалось, что нужно установить для вебсокета binaryType="arraybuffer"
Кому интресно, процесс описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089732/display-image-from-blob-using-javascript-and-websockets)

Answer (score 1):

```
ws.onmessage = m => {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(m.data);
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', image);
}
```